# PHP / SQL: searching against html entities stored in database

Tags: php, mysql, html-entities

I work a lot with languages that use accented characters, e.g. é. I store content in "utf_8_bin" encoded tables AND I convert accented characters to HTML entities too.

So, for example, "Términator" would be stored as "T & eacute ; rminator" (had to spaces in that to stop it rendering online) in the database.

When a user searches for "términator" a match is found because the query is also converted to HTML entities and the SQL query "lowercases" both sides of the argument with "lcase".

The problem I am having now, is that the client wants to be able to search for "Terminator" (no accent on the "e") to get results matching "Términator".

I would prefer not to change the way I store my data, particularly because storing HTML entities solves a number of other problems. So I'm asking in case there's a simpler solution. Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried using the like operator? Also, you may have to double store the data to meet that requirement. One as is, and again with accents and such removed.

Comment: Perhaps comparing the levenshtein of both may work, or something similar... Do you anticipate having a large database for this project?

Comment: @SloanThrasher - I am using the like operator: where lcase('T&eacuterminator') like lcase('%content%'). The content is actually a full article. Double storing the data is quite a feasible solution though - I'll consider doing that if I can't find another solution. Thanks.

Comment: @Shane - Levenshtein would have been perfect for this - except the content is a full article so thousands of words would need to be checked *per article* (they'll be hundreds of articles) and the distance would always have to be at least 8 (&eacute;) - I think. Shame.

Comment: Would it be too much overhead for your usage to replace all instances of é with the letter 'e' for the search?

Comment: If I was going to store a second set of data specifically for searches then that's what I would do. I'm trying to avoid that if I can - that's my backup solution. Right now, the content I have stored needs to be displayed so the accents need to stay.

Comment: I would advise you to sync your MySQL database with a search engine, like Elasticsearch. Though, it does not relate to the task you have now, in the long run it will save from a lot of troubles and you will gain a great performance increase.

Comment: Re "I had to put spaces in it to stop it rendering"... please note that Stackoverflow allows you to mark parts of your text as code. This will display it nicely and stop it rendering. Simply wrap the relevant text with tick mark characters (`).

Comment: *I would prefer not to change the way I store my data, particularly because storing HTML entities solves a number of other problems* -- Unfortunately you will have to change the way you store your data, because you are doing it wrong. The other problems you speak of that you think are being solved by doing this are actually still there; you've just moved the problem rather than solving it, and now that decision is coming back to bite you.

Comment: Sorry; my previous comment sounds harsh. I don't mean to sound that way, but it is a difficult lesson that we all have to learn. Getting the character encoding right is hard. In reality you probably don't need entities at all (except for `&gt;` `&lt;` and `&amp;`), if you just make your site use UTF-8 properly all the way though. There's lots about that here on SO, because it can be a really fiddly thing to get right. But you absolutely need to do it, because otherwise you'll never be able to solve the problem you've asked in this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use the correct collation in your query in your case `utf8_unicode_ci` (This is without the html entities)

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/charset-unicode-sets.html

This collation you use determines which results you get back from you database. And how that characters are compared.

```
SELECT * FROM some_table WHERE title LIKE "Terminator" COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci
```

This query will return records with the title `términator`, `Terminator` etc, note that it does a case insensitive comparison (the `_ci` part in the collation).

The `utf8_unicode_ci` is a bit slower but that's really minimal and you probably wouldn't even notice the difference.

There are more collations that can fit your needs, not sure if there is one which can be used for html entities. You could add your own collation to mysql database to create the htmlentities support yourself something like `utf8_htmlentities_ci`. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/adding-collation.html

Here a nice example with phone numbers https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/ldml-collation-example.html

Comment: This is a good answer. However it won't work for the user as things stand because he's actually storing the HTML entities in the DB. This is wrong. You should not store the HTML entities in your database. The database should contain the actual characters in the text, not any kind of encoding. You should convert the text to contain entities only at the point when you are outputting it into your HTML content. Having entities in the DB breaks the ability to search properly. It will also cause problems if you need to output to a different format than HTML.

Comment: I agree that you shouldn't store the html entities into the database, it creates more complications than it solves. A nice database migration that removes the htmlentities back to the original characters would be the best solution.

Comment: Looks like I've a bit of work to do. I will actually proceed with this: migrate the content without the html entities and then use the suggested collation for searches. I was storing HTML entities in the database because it was (at least used to be) the best way to ensure that accented characters wouldn't be "broken" on display. I guess the cons outweigh the pros now - I had other problems with this like trying to display only the first 100 words of a string. Many thanks for all your help guys.